# Passing JWT as to relying party policy results in "client assertion invalid", reason "jwt format"

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I'm attempting to send a JWT into my relying party policy and referenced through `<InputTokenFormat>JWT</InputTokenFormat>` but having a difficult time getting B2C to validate the token.  I wonder if anyone can spot the problem.

**The Error**

This comes back from B2C after calling the authorize endpoint and passing in the client_assertion on the querystring:

> AADB2C90017: The client assertion provided in the request is invalid: 'client_secret' was used as the verification key

The client_secret is a signing secret, manually generated in the IEF policy area for sharing with the app. But honestly I can't tell if this error is just a helpful factoid: 'client_secret' is the key the policy is trying to validate with, OR, it's telling me *why* the request is invalid: the 'client_secret" was used incorrectly as the verification key.

**From App Insights**

```
              {
              "Key": "Exception",
              "Value": {
                "Kind": "Handled",
                "HResult": "80131500",
                "Message": "The client assertion provided in the request is invalid: 'client_secret' was used as the verification key",
                "Data": {
                  "IsPolicySpecificError": false
                },
                "Exception": {
                  "Kind": "Handled",
                  "HResult": "80131500",
                  "Message": "The validation of the JWT failed. Reason: jwt format",
                  "Data": {}
                }
              }
```

**Decoded JWT**:
(note the `aud` guid is my app's client id)

```
{
  "alg": "HS256",
  "typ": "JWT"
}
.{
  "verified_email": "markarnolditpro@gmail.com",
  "nbf": 1554098875,
  "exp": 1554530875,
  "iat": 1554098875,
  "iss": "https=mytenant.b2clogin.com/34d8169d-0e97-4cc7-a8d0-57c29404f1b1/v2.0/",
  "aud": "7c93185b-05c7-4d72-b8c9-bd62e7bfefc5" 
}
.[Signature]
```

**The URL to the policy:**

```
https://mytenant.b2clogin.com/mytenant.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?p=B2C_1A_Invitation
&client_assertion_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:client-assertion-type:jwt-bearer
&client_assertion=<JWT base64 header.body.signature>
&client_id=7c93185b-05c7-4d72-b8c9-bd62e7bfefc5
&response_mode=form_post
&response_type=id_token
&redirect_uri=http://localhost:34647/
&scope=openid
&nonce=123123123sdfsdfsdf
```

**Signing**

I've created an IEF key, manually generated, signing secret, and shared the value with the app.  I reference the key from the relying part policy as follows: 
`<Key Id="client_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_ADB2CMgtAPISecret" />`

**Generate the Token**

This code is taken from the WingTipGames app for the most part

```
private static string CreateSelfIssuedToken(
        string issuer,
        string audience,
        TimeSpan expiration,
        string signingSecret,
        ICollection<Claim> claims)
    {
        var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        var nowUtc = DateTime.UtcNow;
        var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(signingSecret));
        var signingCredentials = new SigningCredentials(key, "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#hmac-sha256");

        var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
        {
            Audience = audience,
            Expires = nowUtc.Add(expiration),
            IssuedAt = nowUtc,
            Issuer = issuer,
            NotBefore = nowUtc,
            SigningCredentials = signingCredentials,
            Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(claims)
        };

        var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
        return tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);
    }
```

I'm confident the the same signing secret is being used to both sign and validate the JWT.  But I'm really shooting blind as the specific jwt format that's needed. Any thoughts?  So far I'm thinking:

- a simple urlEncoding issue somewhere
- an issue with clocks being out of sync between client and server
- I'm missing some claim or it's specified incorrectly in the token

Thanks
Mark

Comment: Hi @Mark. The `iss` claim (`https=mytenant.b2clogin.com/...`) doesn't actually have an equals symbol in it does it?

Comment: @padgett I had the UrlEncoding messed up, good catch... but sadly the problem remains.

Comment: @ChrisPadgett : I'm testing against a stripped down set of policies just to get JWT validation to work.  In the request that fails, I can copy out the `client_assertion`, paste it into JWT.io, then copy in my signing secret and generate a new token.  Copying the new token into the original request URL works!  Meaning B2C likes the signature.  So it seems something about the way I'm signing the JWT in `CreateSelfIssuedToken` is not working.  I wonder if it's because of changes to the `IdentityModel` classes in my newer Net Core 2.2 app?  Or the B2C signing algorithms have changed?